# Close specific Excel file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

What would be the appropriate PowerShell cmdlet to use to kill a specific Excel file. The command

```
Stop-Process -Name "excel"
```

closes all open Excel applications.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, excel opens `.xlsx` files in one instance of `excel.exe`

Kill the excel.exe will kill all opening workbooks. The `MainWindowTitle` only shows the active workbook, so you will not able to match passive workbooks by the property.

A better way to close a specific workbook is to acquire the excel instance by com object.

Close the workbook matched the `Name` (file name) or `FullName` (file path)

```
$excel = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$excel.Workbooks | %{if($_.Name -imatch "excel file name"){$_.Close()}}
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong . Doesn't seem to work when i tried using Fullname.

Comment: $excel = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$excel.Workbooks | %{if($_.FullName -imatch "M:\Items.xlsx"){$_.Close()}}

Comment: @drdrdr `-imatch` operator is a regular expression, if you not familiar with it, you can easily change `-imatch` to `-like`. e.g. `$_.FullName -like "M:\Items.xlsx"` or even `-eq "M:\Items.xlsx"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
Get-Process excel –ea 0 | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle –like ‘*report.csv*’ } | Stop-Process
```

Here's the official guide from MS:

[Stop-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-6)

Comment: This way Works. But do you have a way of not triggering document recovery when opening the excel file again

Answer (score 0):

```
$Application = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Application.Visible=$True

$workbook = $application.Workbooks.open("C:\mySheet.xlsx")

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$workbook.close($false)
```

The problem is that the window remains open while the dokument is closed.

Hope it still helps.
BR

Comment: Why is it always messing up my formating xD
and removing the first line I write...